# For IOS - How do I align text vertically center in Input from Native Base?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native-base

Currently, the placeholder and the text inside the Input is aligned near to bottom. I want to vertically align this. In android, it is exactly at the center. But in IOS, it is some margins below the center near to the bottom.

```
const styles = {
  formTextStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 17,
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  ItemStyle: {
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
};

export const CustomAuthInput = props => (
  <Item style={styles.ItemStyle} rounded>
    <Input
      style={styles.formTextStyle}
      autoCorrect={false}
      {...props} // doing this provides better control
    />
  </Item>
);
```